# Call back URL generic

Tags: rest-service

we are working on a project to build manage package . We have webservice integration where call back URL needs to be defined so that token can be received from that call and again this token will be used to call another service. Now The challenge is we have created a visualforce page to received the token and it is working fine . And this callback URL needs to be configure in service side as well . Now we know that domain of the visualforce page and the URL is configured . But if it is installed in multiple customer premises then the visualforce page domain will change based on customer salesforce org. which is not possible from service end to configure multiple call back URL .
Hence I am looking for some solution which we can use in this case. If any one has any idea on this please share your thought.

Answer (score 1):

In accordance to the OAuth 2.0 specification, the redirect URIs must be an explicit match. You can specificy multiple callback URIs (one per line) in your app settings if your app setting allows it.

A better solution is for you to have a generic callback URI ( Using force.com sites ) that then redirects back to your actual callback URI. You can use the `state` parameter in the authorization process to identify which URI your app should then redirect the user to from your generic callback URI.